# How to make Delete and Edit methods in MVC without DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository, crud

I am building a simple MVC CRUD without using a database, but just making methods in a Repository model class.

To make it easier to understand i have 2 model classes. MyNote in which i have some properties and NoteRepository in which i have a list with the properties.

Then I've made a NoteController and i have already made Get and Create methods, but i can't seem to figure out what to write to make an Edit and Delete method? Hope you guys can help.

Here you will see some of the code from my project:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyNote mn)
    {
        try
        {
            note.Create(mn);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

this is the create from the Controller.

```
public static List<MyNote> notes = new List<MyNote>();

        public NoteRepository()
    {
        notes.Add(new MyNote() { ID = 1, Titel = "Morgenmad", OprettelsesDato = DateTime.Now, Note = "Spis morgenmad i dag" });
        notes.Add(new MyNote() { ID = 2, Titel = "Frokost", OprettelsesDato = DateTime.Now, Note = "Spis frokost i dag" });
        notes.Add(new MyNote() { ID = 3, Titel = "Aftensmad", OprettelsesDato = DateTime.Now, Note = "Spis aftensmad i dag" });
    }

    public void Create(MyNote mn)
    {
        notes.Add(mn);
    }
```

here is the repository class with the list and the method for the create method.

and please, ask if i have missed something! Thank you :-)

Comment: @HenkHolterman public static List<MyNote> notes = new List<MyNote>();
MyNote just includes properties like ID, Titel, Date and note :-)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Are you only here to make these sorts of comments?
Because if the question doesn't make sense to you, then just don't answer.. 

And FYI - it is not only delete but edit aswell. Try to read the issue instead of commenting about something else.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It has everything to do with asp.net-mvc??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using a List for your in-memory repository. For delete, you can implement something like this:

`public bool Delete (MyNote noteToDelete) {
    return notes.Remove(noteToDelete);
}`

Edit: However, in this case, the list will check for reference equality. Since you have an ID, which I will assume is unique, you can instead do this:

`public bool Delete(MyNote noteToDelete) {
    var matchingNote = notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == noteToDelete.ID);
    return notes.Remove(matchingNote);
}`

You could also implement IEquatable on your MyNote class to change how your notes are compared with each other, and return a valid match when the IDs are the same.

For the IEquatable example, you would want to change the class definition for MyNote to look like:

`public class MyNote : IEquatable<MyNote>`

and add in the following code to the MyNote class:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    Part objAsNote = obj as MyNote;
    if (objAsNote == null) return false;
    else return Equals(objAsNote);
}

public bool Equals(MyNote otherNote) {
    if(otherNote == null) return false;
    return (this.ID.Equals(otherNote.ID));
}

public override int GetHashCode(){
    return this.ID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
It is working now when im deleting, i just have another issue.
Whenever i press the delete in the web-page it doesn't show the Title or Note etc. but it deletes them anyways? :-)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by not showing the Title / Note. All that the delete function would do is remove an item from your list. Typically, for a Delete action, your controller would have two action methods: One that's an HttpGet that takes a Note and returns a page that asks the user if they are sure they want to delete that note, displaying things like the title or notes attached, and an HttpPost, that takes a Note and removes it from your backing data. You want to do it like this so something like a search engine doesn't accidentally wipe our all your data.

Comment: yeah it's what is in the get and post method i have problems with writing too.
I have made a reference for the repository class in the Controller.

In my HttpPost Delete method i have written "note.Delete(mn)" and it works after making the view too. But i don't know what i have to write in the HttpGet to show the title and note attached :-)!

Comment: You'll want to add a GetById(int id) function in your repository that does something like `return notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == id);` Then in the controller have an action like `[HttpGet] public ActionResult Delete(int id) { var noteToDelete = note.GetById(id); if(noteToDelete != null) return View(noteToDelete); return View("NoteNotFound"); }` with your delete view expecting a MyNote object as it's model. edit: Also, if you find my answer to be satisfactory, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Okay, will try that! Thank you for the answers! and i will do ;-) Happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(MyNote noteToEdit)
{
    var oldNote = notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == noteToEdit.Id);

    if(oldNote == null)
        return View(); //With some error message;

    oldNote.Title = noteToEdit.Title;
    oldNote.OprettelsesDato = DateTime.Now;
    oldNote.Note = noteToEdit.Note;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Note");
}

public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var noteToRemove = notes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if(noteToRemove == null)
        return View(); //With some error message;

    notes.Remove(noteToRemove);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Note");
}
```

When you are editing your note, i recommend you to use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) to make your code more easy to maintain.